# Setting all pixels of SDL window

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm using the SDL2 library and want to set in an infinite loop all pixels of my window at once. Is there a more efficient way then going through every pixel of the screen and set it? Can i somehow pass a 2 dimensional vector or something alike directly?
Until now i'm using https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawPoint, but for a window containing about 2 million pixel that is too time consuming (takes about 1/4 of a second).
All suggestions for optimizations are welcome!

Comment: [`SDL_RenderClear`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear)?

Comment: Maybe i should have been more specific about what i want to do.
The pixels are not supposed to all be the same colour, but a picture in which each Pixel can have its own colour.

Comment: Create a surface, fill it with your pixel colours, convert it to texture, draw texture with `SDL_RenderCopy`. What is your source data format and where it comes from?

Comment: @keltar Thanks! That should do it, but I'll need some time to try it. Originally the texture were .bmp files, but i converted them and made them thinner, but now that it just found out SDL has an extra function to read in .bmp files, I'll consider using that.

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to keltar, but now I'd like to close the thread or mark it as answered, but scince the solution was given in a comment and not as an answer i don't know how to do it. ^^'